# What explains the alignment, when resizing, in this bootstrap example

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap form in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ttb0xtn0/) and a simple label + textbox combo.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="af_Email">Email</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="af_Email" readonly="readonly" name="af_Email" 
            placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" 
            required="" value="frizzo@hotmail.com" type="email">
    </div>
</div>
```

When page is expanded (assuming in the col-md-* range), labels right align and the margins are good and the page looks good.

[image]

When I shrink the page to something lesser than col-md-*, the labels left align, the margins to the panel are non-existent and it looks unprofessional:

[image]

How can I add margins (on both side of the panel) when page size lesser than col-md-*?

As a bonus question, can someone explain where in bootstrap this behavior is defined or documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you missed to add `.col-md-12` before `.form-group`.

Here's the update: https://jsfiddle.net/ttb0xtn0/1/

Comment: Ramon, that fixed it.  Can you explain why adding a new div to enclose an existing fixed it?  Since it's a div it should expand to the max anyway, shouldn't it?